# How to get all overlapping (ordered) 3-tuples from an array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a table like the following

```
elems
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
```

I'd like to transform it into something like this:

```
tuple
['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'e']
['v', 'w', 'x']
['w', 'x', 'y']
```

I.e., I'd like to get all overlapping 3-tuples.

My current attempt looks as follows:

```sql
WITH foo AS (
  SELECT ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] AS elems UNION ALL
  SELECT ['v', 'w', 'x', 'y']),
single AS (
  SELECT * FROM
    foo,
    UNNEST(elems) elem
),
tuples AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(elem) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS tuple
  FROM single
)
SELECT * FROM tuples
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(tuple) >= 3
```

But the problem is, it returns some unwanted rows too, i.e., the ones that are "between" the original rows from the `foo` table.

```
tuple
['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'e']
['d', 'e', 'v'] <--- unwanted
['e', 'v', 'w'] <--- unwanted
['v', 'w', 'x']
['w', 'x', 'y']
```

Also, is it guaranteed, that the order of rows in `single` is correct, or does it only work in my minimal example by chance, because of the low cardinality? (I guess there may be a simple solution without this step in between.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select [elems[offset(index - 1)], elems[offset(index)], elems[offset(index + 1)]] as tuple
from your_table, unnest([array_length(elems)]) len,
unnest(generate_array(1, len - 2)) index
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's perfect, because it eliminates the intermediate step, so I don't need to worry about order guarantees there. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below query.

> Also, is it guaranteed, that the order of rows in single is correct, or does it only work in my minimal example by chance, because of the low cardinality?

afaik, it's not quaranteeded without explicit using **WITH OFFSET** in the query.

```sql
WITH foo AS (
  SELECT ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] AS elems UNION ALL
  SELECT ['v', 'w', 'x', 'y']),
single AS (
  SELECT * FROM
    foo,
    UNNEST(elems) elem WITH OFFSET
),
tuples AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(elem) OVER (PARTITION BY FORMAT('%t', elems) ORDER BY offset ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS tuple
  FROM single
)
SELECT * FROM tuples
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(tuple) >= 3;
```

[image]

Comment: Cool idea to use the elements themselves for partitioning. Thanks!

Comment: @TobiasHermann, I've updated query to keep the order of elements, so kindly check it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you another idea

```
create temp function slice(arr ARRAY<string>, pos float64, len float64)
returns array<string> language js as 
r"return arr.slice(pos, pos + len);";
select slice(elems, index, 3) as tuple
from foo, unnest([array_length(elems)]) len,
unnest(generate_array(0, len - 3)) index
```

leaving it up to you to refactor above query to the point when it will look something like

```
select tuple
from foo, unnest(slices(elems, 3)) as tuple
```